# WinSCP downloading to local directory named after today

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

I have written a WinSCP script which downloads files from a remote server to my local directory. My local directory changes everyday.

```
option batch abort
option confirm off

open sftp://sftpsite -hostkey="ssh-rsa ab:cd:....."
synchronize local ?????  /Home/user/
exit
```

I am not sure what my local directory should be.

Comment: So how do you tell what local directory you should use?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use today's date as a name of the target local directory, use [`%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd#` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp):

```
synchronize local C:\Data\%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd# /Home/user/
```

Note that if you are downloading the files to a new folder every day, it's not really synchronization. It is a normal full download. So [`get` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get) might be more meaningful:

```
get /Home/user/* C:\Data\%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd#\
```

Answer (score 0):

So.. I think i figured it out. My local directory should be something like this:

C:\Data\%datestamp%

where datestamp is something which changes everyday and is obtained by running a batch process.

```
 option batch abort
 option confirm off

 open sftp://sftpsite -hostkey="ssh-rsa ab:cd:....."
 synchronize local C:\Data\%datestamp%  /Home/user/
 exit
```